# Why do bytebuffer give buffer overflow exception when buffer is not full

Tags: java, bytebuffer

I'm not sure why the following example gives buffer overflow exception. Hope someone can explain why, and how i can do it correctly.

It's as simple as this:

```
ByteBuffer bf = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
bf.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
bf.putInt(8);
bf.putInt(7); // Throws exception
```

The goal: [0,0,8,7]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the total number of bytes?

Comment: haha, sorry. Forgot to insert a number instead of the variable.

4

Comment: hmm, just a througt i got now... putInt is probably Int32? :P

Comment: @Ikky contrary to C in Java int has a fixed size of 32 bits

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An int is 4 bytes long so you should multiply 4 to the number of int you need to store in your ByteBuffer.

Comment: Yes, thought about that the minute after i asked :/

Thanks

Comment: If it helped you, kindly accept as answer :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#putInt%28int%29) states

> `BufferOverflowException` - If there are fewer than four bytes remaining in this buffer

Your `totalNumberOfBytes` must not be big enough to fit 2 ints, ie. less than 8.